# Android sql lite database handling through SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.exe

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database in my android application. I want to add new record in my database through SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.exe. I have pull the database from the data->data->{my package}->database. But when i try to add a new record through SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.exe i find an error saying "if the table contain fields declared as NOT NULL please select EDIT->PREFERENCES and adjust the default value for new records to insert an empty string". I did that accordingly but found the same error again.

Comment: Are there fields declared as `NUT NULL`?

Comment: yes they are declared as not null

Comment: If that preference does not work, you can maybe put something in those manually. Since you declared them `NOT NULL` you should have something useful to put in there.

Comment: You can answer your own question; please do it.